# kafka auto commit - reset consumer group in c#.net

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

I have topic and consumer group created for it. I started consumer with auto commit enabled. As my consumer is slow now there is lot of lag and as its auto commit the offset is stored.

I have millions of messages and live data so no point is processing old messages. so want to start from last message but kafka is consuming based on last offset stored.
I even started consumer with auto commit and auto offset store disable but since its stored before. It always start from last offset rather than last message.

If i could reset the offset stored then i am planning to use with auto commit disabled and it should start from last message (autooffsetreset = latest). This property though set to latest doesn't work with offset already being committed.

Answer (score 0):

auto.offset.reset = latest / earliest only takes action on the first time you are creating the consumer group,

after creating the consumer group, it lives inside kafka so when consumer is starting it will continue from where it left off.

You can use seek to latest while members are connected to the group,

while members are disconnected:
or consumer-groups.sh command to --reset group --to-latest

you can also --delete the group so the auto.offset
reset would work again when creating the consumer group

Comment: thanks Ran.  so in production scenario i can delete the group/ reset using command option will not be available as developer, seek to latest yes i was trying. but it requires topic partition . i had issues with that 1) it requires topic partition and if i get the topic partition then offset is get property only so can't update it 2) if i only to seek with new topic partition then i get error local partition commit something like this.  3) if i only do seek without committing then offset is still present at kafka server and will restart again from same offset. any example would help

Comment: So your only option is to seek or change group.id, share your example and what error you encountered and we might help you resolve it

Comment: as i understand seek method can be useful but its giving error "no local offset stored" error if i pass the topicpartitionoffset array with offset.end. If i get the topic partition offset from consumer only then don't have set option to override it.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the consumer group and start consuming again. This would recreated the consumer group with the correct `auto.offset.reset`.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group $consumerGroup
```

Of course you can also, if possible, change the consumer group.

Comment: thanks yes but don't want to use the command as it requires kafka server access and already we provisioned topics and acl in production and changing may have impact

Comment: Ok understandable, but what about changing the consumer group (group.id at the consumer) ? That would have no impact on the topic and broker. You even won't run into long re-balancing.

Comment: I got the idea to re provision the ACLs but we used certificate and yes ideally speaking we can reprovision but audit wise its not good idea to do it

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/995.

i used the offset End instead of beginning and once consumer is connected it is starting from current position rather than offset. Please check whether this approach looks ok. its working for me

```
var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(consumerConfig)
.SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) =>
{
   var offsets = partitions.Select(tp => new TopicPartitionOffset(tp, Offset.End));
   return offsets;
})
.Build();
```